# what is the spectrum of a linear map and does 0 belong to it?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, spectral-theory

can somebody help me understand what the spectrum of a linear map is? from what i have seen its the set of lambdas such that A-I(lambda) is not invertible for a linear map A:X->X, so its a set which makes that operator not invertible, could 0 be in this set? an example would be nice as im struggling to visualise this, thanks

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis), right at the top

Comment: May be OP is confused whether $0$ is eigenvalue of $A$?  Note that $A-λI$ is not invertible implies that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A-I$ it may not be an eigenvalue of $A$. Further, if $X$ is finite dimensional then spectrum is nothing but a set of eigenvalues but in case when $X$ is infinite dimensional space this need not be true.

Answer (score 1):

In the finite dimensional case the spectrum is nothing but the set of eigenvalues. The identity matrix is an example of a linear map whose spectrum does not contain $0$.

Comment: Sir, I always saw presence of beauty in your answers.